# Does no variables change in an adiabatic + isothermal system?

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

Adiabatic + isothermal = no heat and temperature change. Does that mean the system will remain as it is?

If it is adiabatic + isovolumetric or adiabatic + isobaric , is it as well no change in any variables at all?

Thank you for helping me to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering a single phase single component closed system, what you say would be true, as it only takes two thermodynamic properties to define a single phase single component closed system.

Comment: this is correct if we restrict to reversible transformations, that yield an equation of the form $X=f(T)$, where $X$ is the other macroscopic coordinate. A counterexample is the free expansion of a perfect gas.

Comment: This answer would be fine if it was amended by @pppqqq's suggestion.